# Automatically toggle iPhone Low Power Mode on set schedule

Tags: ios, battery, settings, power-management

Is there a way built-in, using Shortcuts app or other to schedule toggling of  Low Power Mode on an iPhone?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out as well. There doesn't seem to be a Shortcuts action for settings to enable Low Power mode. Did you ever find a solution?